# Given a modulus p, two primitive roots and the two products of the modular exponentiation attained by swapping the exponents: find the exponents.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quantum-computation, discrete-logarithms

Given a prime $p$, two of its primitive roots $(h_1, h_2)$, $A_1=(h_1^xh_2^y) \mod p,$ $A_2=(h_1^yh_2^x) \mod p$, find $(x,y)$.

**How can it be solved?**

Example:
$p=23$, $(h_1=2, h_2=3)$, $A_1=(2^x3^y) \mod 23 = 16,$ $A_2=(2^y3^x) \mod 23 = 3$,

find $(x,y)$.

I **made some research** and found that in a close future, having a quantum computer with a sufficient number of qubits, in order to implement **Shor's algorithm**, we'll be able to compute discrete logarithms. So, by multiplying $A_1, A_2$ we can obtain the sum of the exponents using the product of the two primitive roots as base (I omit "mod p"):

$A_{1} = h_{1}^{x}h_{2}^{y}$
$A_{2} = h_{1}^{y}h_{2}^{x}$
$A_{1}A_{2} = h_{1}^{x}h_{2}^{y}h_{1}^{y}h_{2}^{x} = h_{1}^{(x+y)}h_{2}^{(y+x)} = (h_{1}h_{2})^{(x+y)}$

But even in this hypothesis, I can't understand if and how it is possible to find **the single exponents**.

Comment: To avoid closing, show some of your effort at solving, and pick a tag that's fitting or explain why it is.

Comment: The answer will not be unique in general (not even unique modulo $p-1$). For example we could have $h_1=h_2$....

Comment: @GregMartin I’m guessing this is in a cryptographic setting, where all that matters is what happens with high probability. Now, it’s true that $h_1 = h_2^k$ for some $k$ coprime to $p - 1$, and so there are always lots of solutions, it’s just that the argument that’s relevant to this case likely requires more care.

Comment: @NicholasPriebe exactly, that's it